# Angular 9 - Download is disallowed. The frame initiating or instantiating the download is sandboxed, but the flag ‘allow-downloads’ is not set

Tags: angular, download

## Hi everyone :)

I'm getting this warning in the console when I try to download a file in the application:
`Download is disallowed. The frame initiating or instantiating the download is sandboxed, but the flag ‘allow-downloads’ is not set. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5706745674465280 for more details.`

component.html

```
<a class="download-document-link" #downloadDocumentLink download></a>
```

component.ts

```
  @ViewChild('downloadDocumentLink') private downloadDocumentLink: ElementRef;
  ....

  private downloadDocument(doc: string): void {
    const source = `data:application/${this.order.docType.toLowerCase()};base64,${doc}`;
    const fileName = `order-${this.order.orderId}.${this.order.docType.toLowerCase()}`;
    const link = this.downloadDocumentLink.nativeElement;

    // IE workaround
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
      saveDocumentIE(doc, fileName, this.order);
    } else {
      link.href = source;
      link.target = '_blank';
      link.download = fileName;
      link.click();
    }
  }
```

The warning is very strange because the download was working before Chrome 83 and I'm not using `iframe`.
Do you have any experience with this?

Comment: checkout this link it may help https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1221  and

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XfLQd9IbJBPAE4IAOvu4EubUaLuICJrDlrmz0Ya_mqQ/edit#

Comment: you can try using filesaver module , to avoid any download issues

Comment: Hi, @LogicBlower. I tried to use ngx-filesaver but the behaviour is the same :/

Comment: can you add a stackblitz demo for the issues you have  ? , may be i can try to find solution as of now , and as it's a browser wide issues , other library probably will be rolling out solution for same or you can rasie a github issues for the particular package

Answer (score 2):

Solution found! This issue was not from Chrome. This is related to our web server config. It didn't have the flag: `Content-Security-Policy "sandbox allow-downloads";` :)